# Eliminate Recursion on Events Triggered Inside Mousewheel Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, mousewheel

I'm working on a project that's using a sort of dummy pagination. The body is set to `overflow: hidden` and currently the only way to navigate the pages is by physically clicking on either links in the nav pane, or on sroll-down/scroll-up buttons. Here's an idea of the events that are triggered when those elements are physically clicked:

```
var links = $('#topnav, .top-mid a'), l = links.length - 1;
var id = 0;

$('.scrollDown, .scrollUp, .top-mid a, body.home #topnav').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is('.scrollDown') && id < l) id++;
    if ($this.is('.scrollUp') && id > 0) id--;
    if ($this.is('#topnav, .top-mid a')) id = links.index(this);

    // Body is animated down or up and elements are
    // shown or hidden depending on what was clicked and
    // and what the var id is currently equal to
});
```

The idea is to trigger exactly ONE click of the scroll button on a mousewheel event. So something close to as simple as this, but that actually works:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e){ // I realize this will not work in FF

    var evt = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    console.log(evt);

    // Scrolling Down
    if (evt < 0) {
        $('.scrollDown').click(); // This fires recursively as long as wheelDelta !== 0
    }
});
```

How can I either force `wheelDelta` to only increment or decrement by one, or, barring that, how can I eliminate the recursion on the click event?

I've been at this for a while, and read lots of posts and haven't been able to crack it. I've also tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), but it's rather heavy and doesn't really suit my project for other various reasons.

Comment: You'd generally be using `$(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);` and in the handler, you check the scrolled distance, usually with a small timer or something, and then trigger one event each time the page is scrolled. Usually one flick of the scrollwheel is 100px, and I think that's cross browser. Why not look at the source code of that plugin to see what it does ?

Comment: The problem with `$(window).on('scroll')` is that it fires when the scroll buttons are clicked. I need a separate event for scrolling the window and physically clicking the buttons. The plugin does not actually scroll the window, it just listens for the event and direction and then animates a container upward `-xpx`. I messed around with it for a couple days before abandoning it and posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this, and of course it turned out to be quite simple. It was a matter of toggling a boolean value inside the `click()` event, but only after all the animations had taken place. Like this:

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).on('mousewheel', function(e){

    var evt = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    // Scrolling Down - Only fire the click event if it hasn't already fired
    if (evt < 0 && !scrolled) {
        $('.scrollDown').click();
    // Scrolling Up
    } else if (evt > 0 && !scrolled) {
        $('.scrollUp').click();
    }
});

// Toggle the scrolled variable inside the original click event
$('.scrollDown, .scrollUp').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is('.scrollDown') && id < l) { 
        id++; 
        scrolled = true; 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            scrolled = false;
        }, 1500); 
    }
    if ($this.is('.scrollUp') && id > 0) { 
        id--; 
        scrolled = true; 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            scrolled = false;
        }, 1500); 
    }
    // Other events here
    // The timeout has to be set high enough to assure
    // that the mousewheel event is finished
});
```